# preg_match formatting results

Tags: php

I am trying to alter a small script but I am not sure about a section of it

basically, I have some data which is used for preg_match pattern which looks like this:

```
 'pattern' => '(13)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})',
  'format' => '($1) $2 $3'
```

the pattern makes sense to me, what I am not sure is how i use "format" to format the output from the preg_match

so the code snippet looks like this:

```
$number = 131166;

if(preg_match($pattern,$number,$match)){
//format the number based on the "format" here
}
```

the output I am looking for is  (13) 11 66

$match is giving me back 3 items as expected, I am just not sure how I would use $1 $2 $3 to mean the first item,second item, third item in the $match array

Comment: You are looking for `preg_replace` it seems.

Comment: It's probably better leaving it as an array. That way you don't need to assign individual variables, and worry about many matches there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace) instead of `preg_match`:

```
$pattern = '/(13)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})/';
$format = '($1) $2 $3';
$number = 131166;

$newNumber = preg_replace($pattern, $format, $number));

echo $newNumber; // '(13) 11 66'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of `preg_match`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(13)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})/', '(\\1) \\2 \\3', $number);
// if $number is 131166 $result now is (13) 11 66
```